# jQuery Mobile select "twitches" to first item after opening for some time

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm having an issue with an annoying "twich" when trying to select an option using jQuery Mobile.

**To reproduce issue:**

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4aXH8/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>          

<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
  <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
  <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
  <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
  <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
</select>
```

1. Open select menu.
2. Hover mouse over "Overnight" option.
3. Wait ~2 seconds, observe that it goes to the "Standard: 7 day" option.

**Notes**

Once this "twitch" event happens, you'll have to hit "Run" in jsfiddler to initiate the state in which this issue occurs in.

HTML was taken straight from the site: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html

Anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: Sorry I can't recreate your problem. What browser or device are you using to test this problem?

Comment: yea it's happening. I guess its a focus issue.

Comment: @Gajotres It's happening under Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by the following line ~11091 of jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js:

```
// This is a fallback. If anything goes wrong (JS errors, etc), or events don't fire,
// this ensures the rendering class is removed after 5 seconds, so content is visible and accessible
setTimeout( hideRenderingClass, 5000 )
```

Commenting it out resolved this issue. Or you can change hideRenderClass() to:

```
function hideRenderingClass() {
if ($html.hasClass( "ui-mobile-rendering" )) {
        $html.removeClass( "ui-mobile-rendering" );
    }
}
```

-Geoff